# Access class member array of unknown size through pointer to first member

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, language-lawyer, type-erasure

I want to be able to handle pointers to objects with an array member of unknown size, and access that array through a type-erased pointer to their common first member. My current attempt is the following:

```
#include <cstddef>

struct node_base
{
    node_base* next;
    int size;
};

template <int n>
struct node
{
    node_base base;
    char data[n];

    node() : base{nullptr, n} {
        static_assert(offsetof(node, data) == sizeof(node_base));
    }
};

void process_queue(node_base* head)
{
    while (head)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < head->size; ++i)
        {
            *(reinterpret_cast<char*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(head) + sizeof(node_base)) + i) = i;
        }

        head = head->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    node<3> a{};
    node<4> b{};
    node<2> c{};

    c.base.next = &b.base;
    a.base.next = &c.base;

    process_queue(&a.base);

    return a.data[2] + c.data[1];
}
```

This code builds up a queue-like structure (nodes `a`,`b` and `c` pointing to each other as "a -> c -> b"), and passes a pointer to the first element to `process_queue`. That function will then traverse the queue and access the `node<n>::data` array stored directly after the `node_base` member, and write the values `0`...`n-1` into its entries.

The challenge is that the nodes have different types, so the queue's `next` pointer point to the `node_base` members of the actual nodes, and I need some what to get to the actual data from there.

Although this seems to work ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zzYYdz6E6)) in the sense that it successfully returns expect value of 3, I am not sure whether this is allowed.

## Question

Assuming I know by some method that the pointer `cur` points to the first member of an object with an array of size `cur->size`, is it legal to access the elements of the `node<n>::data` array by means of the code above? If not, can it be made legal without making `sizeof(node<n>)` larger?

Comment: The "good" way would be a normal downcast, like `static_cast<derived<5>*>(p)->c[2]`. I'm guessing your actual code can't do that because it doesn't know the size (the value of the template argument `n`)? Can you please elaborate on the underlying and actual problem you're trying to solve? Why don't you know the value of `n` when you need to access the array? Why are you using your own array and container classes instead of `std::vector` or `std::array`? Why are you using inheritance? Do you have virtual functions (which will likely make your calculations all wrong) in your real code?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried to address your questions at the bottom of the question, please let me know if something is still unclear

Comment: `base* p = &d;` is pretty meaningless. You will always need to downcast `p` to `derived` for any action, except accessing `p[0]`. But you cannot ask `p` itself whether it's a `derived` (no virtuals) so you need to store this info elsewhere. All in all, what you are doing is not substantially better than `void* b = d;`.

Comment: "I do not know the size n of the derived type at the point where I need to access the array, so a normal down-cast doesn't work." Then what you are trying to do is essentially impossible. You have to downcast. There is no way around it.

Comment: I would argue that the root cause of your problem in not in your code, but rather in your design. What is the inheritance for? What problem in the requirements and analysis is it supposed to solve?

Comment: @n.m. The point is that I know that there will be an array after the base class instance. I just don't know the size at compile time, so I can't write `((derived<5>*)p)->c[3]`. Are you saying there is no legal way to look at that memory, even though I know that an object of a given type is stored there?

Comment: If you don't know the most derived type at compile time, which must be complete, you cannot access array elements. It's the law.

Comment: (Contd) The type includes all the template parameters. If you just know that it is an instance of derived, but don't know which one, you don't know the type.

Comment: If you feel lucky, you can pretend at compile time that you have `derived<100>` or whatever, and do the pointer arithmetic yourself using the size known at run-time. But this is UB and no one can guarantee that it will work.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have reworked the question to give a more concrete example that is more clear I hope. I have also removed inheritance in favor of a normal member containing all the "common" parts of the node data. Please let me know if something about the desired design is still unclear

Comment: @n.m. I don't know the type of `derived<n>` exactly, yes (or `node<n>` in the updated example). But I do know that a sequence of `char` objects is located after the base object in memory, and I do know how many there are. I can hardly believe that there is no way to access those elements in a well-defined way? If it really is, can you point to the relevant part of the standard?

Comment: " I can hardly believe that there is no way to access those elements in a well-defined way?" Yet this is the case.

Comment: @n.m. Does it become legal if I add a `char*` member to the base object that I set to point to the `node<n>::data` member, and use that to access the data array?

Comment: You need to be able to compute the overall size of the object from the template parameter and there is no good way of doing this in C++, except for maintaining an exhaustive map (but if you have such a map you don't need to do any pointer manipulations, you just access the array from within the map).

Comment: I think it is easier and safer to get rid of the template altogether, and just write to the buffer `node_base` followed by `size` characters, then round up to the multiple of `alignof(node_base)` and repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going strictly by the current standard it is undefined behavior already because the pointer arithmetic here:

```
reinterpret_cast<char*>(head) + sizeof(node_base)
```

is undefined. `head` is a pointer to a `node_base` object, which is not pointer-interconvertible with any `char` object at the location. Therefore `reinterpret_cast<char*>(head)` will also be a pointer to the same `node_base` object. As a consequence pointer arithmetic is undefined because the pointed-to type of the expression (`char`) is not *similar* to the actual type of the pointed-to object (`node_base`).

---

However, your intent with the cast to `char*` here is to change the pointer value. You intent to obtain a pointer to the object representation of the `node<n>` object. Casts to `char*` are commonly used to access object representation, but the standard doesn't actually provide for that.

The proposal [P1839](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/592) attempts to incorporate this intended behavior into the standard. With its current wording in revision P1839R5 it would still not make your program well-defined, for multiple reasons:

First, because only `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>` would be possible to obtain a pointer to the object representation, as noted in the limitations section of the proposal.

Even with `unsigned char`, there is still issues under the proposal:

Your classes happen to be *standard-layout*. That's a necessary condition for this to work at all. If they weren't standard-layout, then there generally wouldn't be any way to get from a pointer to one member to a pointer to another member.

But being *standard-layout* guarantees that the `node<n>` object is pointer-interconvertible with its first member subobject. As a consequence, under the proposal it is left open whether `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(head)` will produce a pointer to the first element of the object representation of the `node_base` member or of the `node<n>` object. This is noted as an open issue in the proposal.

Assuming it did however produce a pointer to the object representation of the `node<n>` object as you intent, then the next question would be whether `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(head) + sizeof(node_base)) + i` would be pointer into the object representation of the `char` array member of `node<n>` as well. I am not sure know what the proposal intents for this.

But even if that wasn't an issue, the proposal defines only how it is possible to *read* from the object representation. *Writing* to it is out-of-scope and still UB under the proposal.

So at the very least you would need to keep the outer `reinterpret_cast<char*>` and wrap it in a call to `std::launder` in order to obtain a pointer to the `char` object itself (rather than its object representation or the object representation of the `node<n>` object).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Two questions: Would it "fix" things if I instead changed the object to be effectively a `std::aligned_storage`, into which I would placement-new-allocate the `node_base` object and `data` array? Then the pointer-arithmetic would effectively use `+sizeof(node_base)` for the `data` array. (Since it is very similar to a custom allocator at this point, it seems to me this could be well-defined) If this is still not enough: Would storing a pointer to the data array in `node_base` (initialized in the `node<n>` constructor) and accessing data through that be legal?

Comment: @LukasLang It will depend on how exactly you do it and how strictly you want to read the standard. Storing and accessing through a pointer to the array is not ok, but storing a pointer to the first element of the array and accessing through that is ok and shouldn't involve any casts.

Comment: And if I don't store the pointer, but re-compute it from the pointer to the beginning of the buffer, I assume I'd have to use `std::launder` on the pointer before using it? (Since as far as I understood, only the pointer returned by `new (addr) ...` is technically allowed to access the object allocated at `addr`, right?)

Comment: @LukasLang Yes, if you use the buffer pointer (and the buffer _must_ be an array of `std::byte` or `unsigned char`), you can do pointer arithmetic in it freely but need `std::launder` to access nested objects. `new` essentially already does that `std::launder` for you on its return value. However, instead of `std::aligned_storage` I would suggest just directly using a `unsigned char` or `std::byte` array together with the `alignas` attribute to get the alignment right. I am sure you can find a lot of discussion about `std::aligned_storage` and its potential issues/deprecation.

Comment: @LukasLang However, the inverse, going from a pointer to the nested object to a pointer to a buffer element is generally not possible, even with `std::launder`. See its preconditions. Note also that, with few exceptions relating to `const`/reference (sub-)objects, no compiler actually uses these kinds of UB for optimization purposes at the moment as far as I am aware. So you are already worrying about the details more than most do.

Comment: Thank you once again for the detailed answer!

Comment: @LukasLang Of course, if you place multiple objects into a buffer, you also need to make sure that each one is properly aligned and you'll need to call destructors for each constructed object manually if that is required, which you won't be able to do that if you don't know the original type of the object including the template argument containing the length. I don't know what exactly the goal is, but trying to emulate variable-size types like this is usually not a good idea and there are probably better alternatives. All said above, getting it fully correct in all contexts is still tricky.